# Microsoft Project: how to enter "planned duration", "actual duration", keep them forever and make Project plan everything right?

Tags: microsoft-project

I want to:

1. Enter *planned duration*. Say, 1 day. (And make it the *duration* value)
2. Keep changing an estimation of *completion percentage* as I do work. (And make the *duration* change starting from "1 day" to whatever the real value will be)
3. Enter *actual duration* after finishing the task. (And make "duration" equal it.)
4. Even if I've spent less than "1 day", be able to set *completion percentage* to 100% and mark task as done/inactive.
5. Keep *planned duration* at initial value whatever the real amount spent is.

How to achieve that?

I know that there are *baseline*, *scheduled* etc columns, but I can't figure anything out.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve, but trying to manage tasks using the percentage complete is never a good idea in my view. You are better off exposing the following columns and working with them:

- Work
- Remaining Work
- Actual Work

Work is your estimate of how long the task will take and it is ALWAYS the sum of Actual Work and Remaining Work.

Remaining Work is the current number of hours (or days or whatever) that is left to complete the task and is ALWAYS Work minus Actual Work

Actual Work the real number of hours (or days or whatever) you have actually completed and is ALWAYS equal to Work - Remaining Work

If you change Actual work then project will automatically calculate Remaining Work and if you change Remaining Work then project will automatically calculate the new Work value

Similarly if you modify Work then project will auto-calculate the new Remaining Work value

All the while this is happening Project will automatically work out the completed percentage for you equal to the ratio of Actual Work to Work...

It is a much more accurate and intuitive way of managing and tracking the progress of tasks.